# 13" Mid 2015 Macbook Pro Retina completely slows down on low battery and shuts off at 5%

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, hardware, sleep-wake, power

So recently, I was given a 2015 13" Retina Macbook Pro with a completely dead battery. I replaced it with an iFixit battery and immediately noticed some strange behavior. First, it drains a bit quickly for a battery that reports more than 100% health on coconutbattery (which I don't think even should be possible). Gets about 5 hours tops just with basic web browsing, youtube and typing things at full screen backlight. And when it does get low, I don't see any sort of low battery alert that usually shows up. And as mentioned before, at low battery it starts slowing down and then completely shuts off at around 5% instead of going to sleep and crashes without warning which is annoying if there is work that I haven't saved. If I try booting the computer up after it crashes, I see an apple logo but I never make it to the OS unless I charge. I tried calibrating and power cycling multiple times, resetting SMC, PRAM/NVRAM multiple times to no avail. I asked somewhere else and was told there was a problem with my logic board which I have a hard time believing since this problem never existed with the old battery as far as I know. After running a terminal command, I found that at around where the machine shuts off, the battery voltage is barely at 10V at 7% battery. Could I have a defective battery? Or could it actually be the logic board? Or maybe a problem somewhere else? Any help is appreciated.[image: Here is a CoconutBattery screenshot at 100% battery][image: Here is a CoconutBattery screenshot at 7% battery]

Comment: It's a hardware problem. As such, it needs hands-on visible inspection. Take it to an Apple Store or other repair shop.

Comment: I don't think apple will look at this one since it's considered "vintage" on their own website. I don't live near any other repair stores either. It would help to have a general idea of what specifically may be wrong so I may be able to contact iFixit and tell them that their battery may be defective and so I can replace/repair whatever the broken part may be.